# How to convert character column to numeric in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, dataformat

Example of values in the column are:

```
$3,459.09
$98.00
$6,789,123.15
$5,435.00
```

I can remove the dollar sign by using a substring, but I am not able to find a way to convert character to numeric.

I tried a couple of options
1. `to_number(billed_amount) end as paid_amount_value`
2. `cast ( billed_amount as  INT) as paid_amount_value`

Error:
for 1st:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

for2nd:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

Answer (score 2):

use `TO_Number` and format `'$999,999,999.99'`

```
   select TO_Number('$3,459.09','$999,999,999.99') from dual
```

so in you case

```
select TO_Number(column_name,'$999,999,999.99') from table_name
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9f5c56470b8899080774a32c429999c9)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using double as your datatype use double. You need to remove comma's and empty spaces if present

Answer (score 0):

Your column values do have double values so you have to convert them to decimal. You can use To_number it will take care of it..

If you observe in your error message the values do have spaces in between. 
So, Try to remove them then cast their datatype.

`to_number(billed_amount) as paid_amount` works for you [to_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140)

To replace empty spaces you can use `replace` [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm)